# android browser does not open url when clicked one more times

Tags: android

```
HERE İS MY MAİN XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp">

<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="tabPane" />

<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/address_bar"
    android:layout_width="270px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="http://" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/go_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/address_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/address_bar"
    android:text="GO" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/new_Tab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/go_Button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/go_Button"
    android:text="NewTab" />

</RelativeLayout>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="2dp" />
</LinearLayout> 
</TabHost>
```

HERE İS MY MAİN ACTİVİTY FİLE:

```
package com.example.androidtablayoutactivity;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TabHost tabHost;
    TabSpec photospec;
    TabSpec songspec;
    Intent songsIntent;
    Button go;
    Button newTab;
   TextView text;
   Intent photosIntent ;
   private int counter=0;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_tab_layout);
       go=(Button)findViewById(R.id.go_Button);
       newTab=(Button)findViewById(R.id.new_Tab);
       text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.address_bar);
       tabHost = getTabHost();
       go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Tab for Photos
            go();
        }
    });












    }
    public void go(){
         photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("");
            // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
         URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL( text.getText().toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


            if(counter==0){
                photospec.setIndicator(url.getHost().replace("www."," ").replace(".com"," "));
                photosIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                photosIntent.setClass(this, PhotosActivity.class);
                photosIntent.putExtra("URL1", text.getText().toString());


            photospec.setContent(photosIntent); 
            tabHost.addTab(photospec);
            }
            else{

                tabHost.getTabWidget().removeView(tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0));
                photospec.setIndicator(url.getHost().replace("www."," ").replace(".com"," "));
                photosIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                photosIntent.putExtra("URL1", text.getText().toString());
                photosIntent.setClass(this, PhotosActivity.class);



            photospec.setContent(photosIntent); 
            tabHost.addTab(photospec);
            }
            counter++;
    }

}
```

HERE İS MY OTHER ACTİVİTY WHİCH MAKİNG BROWSER PROCESS

```
package com.example.androidtablayoutactivity;



import com.example.androidtablayoutactivity.SongsActivity.web;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class PhotosActivity extends Activity{

     WebView web;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photos_layout);

        web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.setWebViewClient(new web());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras==null){
            web.loadUrl("");
        }
        else
        {
            web.loadUrl(extras.getString("URL1"));
        }





    }
      public class web extends WebViewClient{

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview,String url){
                webview.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        }

}
```

HERE İS İTS LAYOUT FİLE

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >



    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="385dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

İ am doing browser in android with go and new tab button  when i click first time go button mybrowser is going to url which i want however when i click one moretimes  my address does notchange

Answer (score 0):

I am removing the rest part as its not what your looking for 
**Edit** click [here](http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.in/2011/04/adding-tabs-dynamically-in-android.html)

Comment: i don't how to use onResume or reload method can you give me more information

Comment: can you tell me the flow of your application so that I can understand it better

Comment: there is editext which i write url go button and new tab button.when i click go button first time it creates a new tab and open url with this code      photospec.setIndicator(url.getHost().replace("www."," ").replace(".com"," "));
                photosIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                photosIntent.setClass(this, PhotosActivity.class);
                photosIntent.putExtra("URL1", text.getText().toString());


            photospec.setContent(photosIntent); 
            tabHost.addTab(photospec);

Comment: as you see to open url iam creating a new intent send it to other class which is name PhotosActivity this class layout has webwiew.the url which is come from main activity ,in photosActiviy class,is opening this is the flow .

Comment: if new tab button is clicked,it creates new tab but my browser starts with no tab when go button is clicked firsttime ,it creates first tap after clicked onemoretimes go button it doesnot create tab i mean go button only creates first tab ,it's main job is opening the url

Comment: when your clciking go is the url changing in your web process? I want to make sure whether the problem is really with webView ?

Comment: i could not understand webprocess exactly.when i click go button first time myown browser is opening url but second or third click etc.. when i enter different url it does not open

Comment: WEBview is using my browser not android's default browser